# Why does Paradise PD not lampoon Donald Trump with more regularity?

Tags: paradise-pd

I have noticed that the Netflix series *Paradise PD* (2018-present) regularly shafts Joe Biden, Tucker Carlson, Fox News, CNN, etc, often with some extremely vulgar representations, but Donald Trump usually gets a pass, or at least it seems like he is treated less harshly.

Joe Biden is presented naked and swinging his dick on at least 3 episodes, and going "Oh Yeah!" to some extremely scurrilous representations in at least 3 other episodes. ..

They expose Tucker Carlon's allegedly tiny dick with vulgar regularity.

But Trump...You would he would be a good source of material.

Is there an out-of-universe reason for this? Is it because Trump is extremely litigious when he is being exposed?

Here is the issue: many complain of over-saturation of Trump jokes, yet the series covered almost the entire Trump Admin.

Comment: Personally i think it was Trump Fatigue... Same reason South Park didn't feature Mr Garrison in every episode. If you joke to much about a subject it stops being funny and it becomes boring and repetitive. Especially if several other programs are already making jokes about it.

Comment: @A.bakker I got the same reaction on SF&F...so I deleted the Q and re-posted here. That does not explain the extreme paucity of Trump-oriented jokes.

Comment: well if all sources say the same... but simply said people like more variation. Same reason why eventually the Zombie craze and Vampire craze passed.

Comment: That sounds like a pass...and exactly how are Vampire movies declasse? If anything, they are more popular than ever.

Comment: I vote to close, there is no possible way to know for certain why a writer uses one character more often than another or not